# How to resolve "CRIT 002 Error unmarshaling config into struct: 21 error(s)" in first-network setup?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm working through the Hyperledger "fabric-samples" docs and believe that I have followed all the prerequisite steps to arrive at the point where I invoke

```
me@TheBrick MINGW64 ~/go/src/fabric-samples (v1.1.0)
$ cd first-network/

me@TheBrick MINGW64 ~/go/src/fabric-samples/first-network (v1.1.0)
$ ./byfn.sh -m generate
```

The process throws back an error and I've been unable to find a solution yet.

The output:

```
Generating certs and genesis block for channel 'mychannel' with CLI timeout of '10' seconds and CLI delay of '3' seconds
Continue? [Y/n] y
proceeding ...
/c/Users/me.THEBRICK/go/src/fabric-samples/bin/cryptogen

##########################################################
##### Generate certificates using cryptogen tool #########
##########################################################
+ cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml
org1.example.com
org2.example.com
+ res=0
+ set +x

/c/Users/me.THEBRICK/go/src/fabric-samples/bin/configtxgen
##########################################################
#########  Generating Orderer Genesis block ##############
##########################################################
CONSENSUS_TYPE=solo
+ '[' solo == solo ']'
+ configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis -channelID byfn-sys-channel -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block
2019-02-01 10:17:00.647 GMT [common/configtx/tool] main -> INFO 001 Loading configuration
2019-02-01 10:17:00.675 GMT [common/configtx/tool/localconfig] Load -> CRIT 002 Error unmarshaling config into struct:  21 error(s) decoding:

* '' has invalid keys: capabilities, channel
* 'Application' has invalid keys: Capabilities, Policies
* 'Orderer' has invalid keys: Policies
* 'Organizations[0]' has invalid keys: Policies
* 'Organizations[1]' has invalid keys: Policies
* 'Organizations[2]' has invalid keys: Policies
* 'Profiles[SampleDevModeKafka]' has invalid keys: Capabilities, Policies
* 'Profiles[SampleDevModeKafka].Application' has invalid keys: Capabilities, Policies
* 'Profiles[SampleDevModeKafka].Application.Organizations[0]' has invalid keys: Policies
* 'Profiles[SampleDevModeKafka].Consortiums[SampleConsortium].Organizations[0]' has invalid keys: Policies
* 'Profiles[SampleDevModeKafka].Consortiums[SampleConsortium].Organizations[1]' has invalid keys: Policies
* 'Profiles[SampleDevModeKafka].Orderer' has invalid keys: Capabilities, Policies
* 'Profiles[SampleDevModeKafka].Orderer.Organizations[0]' has invalid keys: Policies
* 'Profiles[TwoOrgsChannel].Application' has invalid keys: Capabilities, Policies
* 'Profiles[TwoOrgsChannel].Application.Organizations[0]' has invalid keys: Policies
* 'Profiles[TwoOrgsChannel].Application.Organizations[1]' has invalid keys: Policies
* 'Profiles[TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis]' has invalid keys: Capabilities, Policies
* 'Profiles[TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis].Consortiums[SampleConsortium].Organizations[0]' has invalid keys: Policies
* 'Profiles[TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis].Consortiums[SampleConsortium].Organizations[1]' has invalid keys: Policies
* 'Profiles[TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis].Orderer' has invalid keys: Capabilities, Policies
* 'Profiles[TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis].Orderer.Organizations[0]' has invalid keys: Policies
+ res=1
+ set +x
Failed to generate orderer genesis block...
```

This is my reference point:

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.0/build_network.html

NB I have followed the steps to get to this point, and noted the info about "These instructions have been verified to work against the version “1.0.3” tagged Docker images". To that end I ran this

```
curl -sSL https://URL | bash -s 1.0.3
```

(the prerequisites specify 1.06)

```
curl -sSL https://URL | bash -s 1.0.6
```

I get the same result, regardless, both 1.0.3 and 1.0.6

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Unless you are using these old versions for a particular reason I would suggest removing all Docker Images, and the fabric-samples tree then start afresh with 1.4 of everything (the "latest" version).

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html